# How to create frequency data for a histogram?

Tags: python

I am importing an excel file with only one column of data and want to create a histogram. I want the x-axis to be the data itself and the y-axis the frequency of that data.

How do I create a dictionary that counts the frequency of the data?

I know I need to create two dictionaries:

```
x = The data from the excel file 
y = [] what goes here?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an input like this:

```
x_orig=[1993, 1998, 1999, 1997, 1996, 1993, 1995, 1996]
```

The most efficient and scalable way is to use the library `collections` for the `y` and make a set of the `x_orig` to avoid repetitions:

```
from collections import Counter

y=Counter(x_orig)
x=set(x_orig)
```

Result:

```
x={1993, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999}
y=Counter({1993: 2, 1998: 1, 1999: 1, 1997: 1, 1996: 2, 1995: 1})
```

You can then easily plot these two variables.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to reinvent the wheel. Numpy provides the tools you need for this project.

```
import numpy as np 

my_column = np.random.random(20) # this is the column you load from Excel
my_bins = np.linspace(0,1,num=5) # 4 bins in your histogram      
my_hist = np.histogram(my_column,bins = my_bins) 
print (my_hist[0]) # this is your freqency distribution
```

Output:

```
[6 4 5 5]
```